# Outlook refuses password from CryptProtectData()

Tags: c#, c++, outlook

I'm developing a tool to import Outlook profiles using a PRF file but it does not import the password, so I have to manually add it to the registry.

I've spent lots of hours reading, testing and debugging this procedure and managed to figure out how everything works, except that Outlook refuses the password generated by CryptProtectData(). I've tried using both the C# .NET wrapper ProtectedData.Protect() and a C++ DLL calling CryptProtectData(), all to no avail.

Whenever I change the password on the registry and open Outlook, it shows the credential dialog. If I type the password then it successfully logs into my email.

Here is the C# code using the .NET wrapper:

```
RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows Messaging Subsystem\\Profiles\\MyProfile\\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\\0000000b", true);
Byte[] Password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyPassword");
Byte[] EncPassword = ProtectedData.Protect(Password, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
RegKey.SetValue("IMAP Password", EncPassword);
```

This code generates a binary data with 234 bytes, 39 bytes less than the password generated by Outlook (273 bytes).

Here is the C++ code:

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT DATA_BLOB crypt(BYTE *input) {
    DATA_BLOB DataIn;
    DATA_BLOB DataOut;
    BYTE *pbDataInput = input;
    DWORD cbDataInput = strlen((char *)pbDataInput)+1;
    DataIn.pbData = pbDataInput;    
    DataIn.cbData = cbDataInput;

    if( !CryptProtectData(&DataIn, L"IMAP Password", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &DataOut) )
    {
        printf("Encryption error");
    }

    return DataOut;
}
```

The C# code calling the DLL:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct DATA_BLOB
{
    public int cbData;
    public IntPtr pbData;
}

[DllImport("MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern DATA_BLOB crypt(Byte[] input);

(...)

RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows Messaging Subsystem\\Profiles\\MyProfile\\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\\0000000b", true);
Byte[] Password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyPassword");
DATA_BLOB BlobData = crypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyPassword"));
Byte[] EncPassword = new Byte[BlobData.cbData];
Marshal.Copy(BlobData.pbData, EncPassword, 0, BlobData.cbData);

RegKey.SetValue("IMAP Password", EncPassword);
```

This code generates a password with 256 bytes, still not the 273 bytes I get from Outlook.

My guess is that these missing bytes are from a specific entropy I'm not using or even some detail I'm missing.

Any tip on the right direction will help a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try UTF-16 encoding of the password ? Which version of outlook are you using ?

Comment: Also, do not include terminal 0 of the string in the blob size.

Comment: What version of Outlook is this?

Comment: This code specifically is for Outlook 2010. I know 2013 and 2016 changed the algorithm and registry location, but I figured I'd start with 2010 and then move to the other two. Will try your recommendations @MichaelDoubez!

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```
DWORD cbDataInput = strlen((char *)pbDataInput)+1;
```

When you call crypt from C#:

```
crypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyPassword"));
```

The `GetBytesCall` is literally retuning a byte array, of all characters in "MyPassword" (`M` to the `d`) but without a null terminating byte.

So when you invoke `strlen`, you might be getting more characters consumed from the data blob array, `input` than you think.  Further, that  `+1` is not guaranteed to be including a null byte.

Change your `crypt` function to be:

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT DATA_BLOB crypt(BYTE *input, DWORD cbDataInput)
    DATA_BLOB DataIn;
    DATA_BLOB DataOut;
    BYTE *pbDataInput = input;
    DataIn.pbData = pbDataInput;    
    DataIn.cbData = cbDataInput;
```

And invoke it as follows:

```
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyPassword");
DATA_BLOB BlobData = crypt(passwordBytes, passwordBytes.length);
```

Or if you need the null byte passed:

```
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyPassword" + "\0");
DATA_BLOB BlobData = crypt(passwordBytes, passwordBytes.Length);
```

I'm not sure if that will resolve all your issues with passing passwords back and forth, but the above is the better way to pass an array of bytes between managed and native code.

Answer (score 0):

Try add some zeros to password bytes array:

```
...
crypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyPassword").AddZeros());
...

private static IEnumerable<byte> AddZeros(this IEnumerable<byte> pass)
{
    foreach (var b in pass)
    {
        yield return b;
        yield return 0;
    }

    yield return 0;
    yield return 0;
}
```

It must be done with POP3 password, but I'm not sure about IMAP password.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that the problem is that you cannot import the password generated using CryptProtectData into Outlook. And, the different length of the password could be the reason.

Here is what I think.
I think that the encryption method that Outlook uses to encrypt password is different from that of CryptProtectData. In order to decrypt anything encrypted by CryptProtectData, you need to be at the same computer that you used to encrypt. See remarks at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata). But, Outlook supports access from different computers with the same credential. As Outlook tries to decrypt the password, it assumes that the password is generated by it's chosen method. If it's found that the encryption method is different due to different algorithm, or enthropy, it fails to decrypt the password and shows the error.

In order for you to import password directly into the registry, you might want to figure out how Outlook encrypts the password that the user inputs for his/her password.